# Which terminal based tool can I use to display only the source and destination IPs of all packets

Tags: tcpdump

I am currently using `ngrep` or `tcpdump`in conjunction to `grep` to display destinations and sources of all incoming and outgoing packets.

Would you suggest a better way to achieve this?

Comment: products recommendations are off-topic here but short answer : no. If those tools do the work, why looking for something else? BTW there's a [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very popular capture tool [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org) includes a CLI tool named `tshark` which can do what you want:

```
$ sudo tshark -T fields -e ip.addr
Capturing on eth1
10.48.169.25,10.48.37.151
10.48.37.151,10.48.169.25
10.48.37.197,10.48.37.151
10.55.131.167,10.48.37.151
10.55.131.167,10.48.37.151
```

See the [man page for tshark](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) for more options, e.g. to replace the comma with something else:

```
$ sudo tshark -T fields -e ip.addr -E aggregator="-"
Capturing on eth1
10.55.131.167-10.48.37.151
10.55.131.167-10.48.37.151
10.48.37.141-10.48.37.151
```

Note that this displays the source and destination ip address, in that order. Since you wrote `to display destinations and sources` I'm not sure if you want them in that order instead, I'm not sure if that is possible. If you also want source/destination *ports* then you may need to tweak the `-e` argument a bit.

Also note that I'm in no way *recommending* to use tshark, for all I know it could eat your data; I'm just stating that it has the options you are looking for ;-)